# Getting new value from a service doesn't reload the view

Tags: angular, http, service

I have a problem with rendering datas who are obtained by a service. Here is the situation :

I have a service who is getting value from a distant API who is working with an Observable:

```
@Injectable()

export class myService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getData(listLength: number): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/${listLength}`)
                .map((res: any) => this.convertResponse(res));
}
```

}

A component who get values from my service and who store them in a var called data :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

data: Data[];

constructor(
    private myService: myService,
    private alertService: AlertService 
) {  }

loadData(length: number) {
    this.myService.getData(length).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
            this.data= res.json();
        },
        (res: any) => this.onError(res.json())
    );
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.loadData(5);
}

private onError (error) {
    this.alertService.error(error.message, null, null);
}
}
```

And a view who is rendering my data :

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr *ngFor="let oneData of data">
     <td>{{oneData.attr1}}</td>
     <td>{{oneData.attr2}}</td>``
  </tr>    
</table>
<button  (click)="loadData(10)">Show more</button>
```

The problem is the following one :

At the first rendering, there is no problem, data are well loaded but when I click on the button  nothing happen. However, the request is send to my distant server. I have to click a second time and then it finaly reload the view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried triggering change detection manually?

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core"; //<-- import

constructor(
    private myService: myService,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef //<-- inject
) {  }

loadData(length: number) {
    this.myService.getData(length).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
            this.data= res.json();
            this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); //<-- use
        },
        (res: any) => this.onError(res.json())
    );
}
```

Comment: _"object reference is not changing"_ `data` gets a new value and it's the only relevant property.

Comment: @zeroflagL you are absolutely correct. Since the object reference problem occurs a lot, I immediately jumped to a conclusion. Thanks!